# Hashing data. Appropriate algorithm?

Tags: memory-management, hash, performance

I'm looking for a way to identify data, such that I prevent it from being loaded more than once in memory. I thought a good method of doing this is to create a hash for each data buffer and use that as a sort of an id.

The data that I'll need to hash ranges from 8 kB images, to 40 kB animations, to 3–5 MB music files, to <0.5 MB sound files. What do you think is the best hashing algorithm for my case? For that matter, is hashing the data the way to go, or should I think of some other way to identify data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of strong algorithms in wide use:

- sha512 (128 bytes)
- sha384 (96 bytes)
- sha224 (56 bytes)
- sha1 and ripemd160 (40 bytes)
- md5 (32 bytes) (*like older md4 and md2*)

a weaker one
  * CRC (10 bytes)

A general rule of thumb:

- collision probability increases with the number of elements in your collections, **not** with their size
- collision probability decreases with the number of bits in the checksum

Hashing *is* the way to go. Just remember that for very very very large collections of items, you should consider the probability of getting a collision (i.e. use a hash lookup followed by a linear search by contents).

As long as you seem to be storing files, it is probably nice to make a compound key:

- hash of contents
- file name
- file length

This has the following advantages:

1. has collisions are off the table for all practical purposes because the chance of getting a collision for different data samples *of the same length* is enormously lower than the risk of getting a collision with just any data random samples
2. your collection is immediately *content addressable* (meaning: you don't need the filename to lookup the contents; you could use the content hash to scan for duplicates by another name, because the hash doesn't depend on the name)

$0.02

Answer (score 0):

I would start by comparing the file sizes. If they are the same you could use some fast hash algorithm such as Adler32 or VMAC-64.